# Get the last active day of a user in each year since he/she signed up

Tags: sql, oracle

I have DATE logs for users when he/she was active.
 I want to filter out his/hers last active day in each year, since he/she joined the service.

example:

```
logged dates
------------
12-1-2015
1-7-2015
21-12-2015
1-1-2016
2-2-2017
9-9-2017
12-10-2017
30-12-2017

expected Output
---------------
21-12-2015
1-1-2016
30-12-2017
```

Comment: Expected input: [ask]

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
select max(logged_date)
from logs
group by extract(year from logged_date)
order by max(logged_date);
```